# Haskell: Sort by height in descending order

Tags: haskell

I have a list of list as:

`[[4,7,9],[7,4,9],[9,4,7],[5,8,9],[8,5,9],[9,5,8]]`

I want to reverse sort them based on base area (3rd side)

eg. `sort [[4,7,9],[5,8,9]]` should yield `[[5,8,9],[4,7,9]]`
since 4+7=11 < 5+8=13

I have implemented the following function:

`quicksort (s:xs) = quicksort[x | x <- xs, x!!0+x!!1 < s!!2] ++ [s] ++ quicksort[x | x <- xs, x!!0+x!!1 >= s!!2]`

But it doesn't give the correct output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a general tip, almost unreadable list comprehension should be avoided. Always try and use a prelude algorithm with a lambda in this sort of scenario!

Comment: Probably both instances of `s!!2` should be `s!!0+s!!1`. With that change (and the obvious base case) your code seems to do what you ask for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use [`sortOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn) which is made exactly for this sort (no pun intended) of thing? Then, you can do this in one line:

```
ghci> import Data.List (sortOn)
ghci> sortOn (\[x,y,z] -> negate (x+y)) [[5,8,9],[4,7,9],[9,4,7],[8,5,9],[9,5,8],[7,4,9]]
[[9,5,8],[5,8,9],[9,4,7],[8,5,9],[4,7,9],[7,4,9]]
```

That aside, if your inner lists always have length 3, they should probably be tuples instead, in which case, you would have

```
ghci> sortOn (\(x,y,z) -> negate (x+y)) [(5,8,9),(4,7,9),(9,4,7),(8,5,9),(9,5,8),(7,4,9)]
[(9,5,8),(5,8,9),(9,4,7),(8,5,9),(4,7,9),(7,4,9)]
```

Comment: `negate` is fine, there's also [`Down`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#t:Down) which reverses an ordering and is what I would have chosen here I think.